# Show alternate result based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with below data

```
id      name            gender(Enum : Male,Female)
1       John Doe        Male
2       Panther Jow     Male
3       Faran Aktar     Female
4       Rohan Fusi      Male
5       Soham Das       Female
6       Rohit Dutta     Female
7       Sozi Petacus    Male
8       Tuhin Dtui      Male
```

I want an SQL query where result should view with one Male and one Female then again one Male and one Female continuously. If after male or female result if can not get next female or male data then all result will show. Like this

```
   id      name            gender(Enum : Male,Female)
    1       John Doe        Male
    3       Faran Aktar     Female
    2       Panther Jow     Male
    5       Soham Das       Female
    4       Rohan Fusi      Male
    6       Rohit Dutta     Female
    7       Sozi Petacus    Male 
    8       Tuhin Dtui      Male
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT rnk, name ,gender
FROM (
  SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN id, name, @y:=IF(@gender=gender,@y+1,1) AS rnk, @gender:=gender AS gender
  FROM (SELECT @gender:=NULL) AS x
  JOIN test
  ORDER BY gender, name DESC
) AS t
ORDER BY rnk ASC, gender DESC;
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4752/9)**

Comment: @TapasKarmakar:- Define not working. I have added the link and its working for me. Please check the link with the output.

Comment: @TapasKarmakar:- To give it a try, I must know what is wrong with the present query and what is your expectation and where the present query is failing for you?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this -

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM <table_name> 
    WHERE IF( gender =  "Male",  "Female",  "Male");
```